# JavaScript Colour Picker with Hex Converter

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am trying to build a JavaScript colour picker on my website. It currently works correctly, but I want it to also write the hex value. The hex converter also works fine, but I think I'm having trouble with the actual converting parameters. Take a look at this.

```js
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
    var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
      green = document.getElementById("green").value,
      blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    display.style.background = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    document.write(rgbToHex(red + ", " + green + ", " + blue));
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="tools">
  <div class="picker">
    <P>Red</P> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="red" value="115">
    <p>Green</p> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="green" value="10">
    <p>Blue</p> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="blue" value="162">
    <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
```

It should actually write the hex value to the document, but that does not seem to be working.

Thanks,
Rat (Joey)

Comment: Your  problem is not calling the function with 3 parameters. Use your browser dev tools for debugging

Comment: Take a look at the errors in your browser console and see if you can figure out what is causing them. Also, don't use `document.write` because it will overwrite everything in your document.

Comment: @charlietfl I have a screenshot of the browser console... I have 4000 error, but they are just google API errors, this is the screenshot of the error: https://theflyingrat.com/repos/uploads/Screenshot%20(167).png

Comment: @Herohtar take a look at the above comment and also, document.write doesn't overwrite everything, it works when I replace the variables in the code with actual numbers.

Comment: The errors only show up once you try moving the slider. Hint: take a look at your `rgbToHex` function call and what is being passed to it. Also, once you fix the code in your snippet you will see that `document.write` does indeed overwrite the document content.

Comment: @Herohtar I don't actually know what's wrong with the function, I have edited the  document.write  to alert() but still, no alert will come up. The function does indeed work, but it's just the parameters I think... The version of the code without the red + green + blue, replaced with 8, 16, 36 will work... It's just the parameters not actually being able to work... Sorry if this reply sounds confusing.

Comment: `rgbToHex` takes 3 parameters, but your code `rgbToHex(red + ", " + green + ", " + blue)` is *not* passing 3 parameters; it is passing a single concatenated string. It should be `rgbToHex(red, green, blue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it helps:

```js
function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
    var red = document.getElementById("red").value,
      green = document.getElementById("green").value,
      blue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    display.style.color = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
    display.innerHTML = rgbToHex(red , green , blue);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="tools">
  <div class="picker">
    <P>Red</P> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="red" value="115">
    <p>Green</p> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="green" value="10">
    <p>Blue</p> <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="blue" value="162">
    <div id="display" style = "width:50px; height:50px"></div>
  </div>
```